# Graphite Live Graph URL in Nagios

Tags: auto-update, nagios, graphite

I would like to embed a Graphite live graph in Nagios.

So I create it in the Graphite Composer. Click on "Auto-Refresh" and put "Select Recent Data" to e. g. 5 days.

Then I copy the short direct URL to this graph to the pasteboard and insert it as the "Action URL" in Nagios.

When I then click on the Action URL in Nagios, the whole Graphite Dashboard is displayed and no Auto-Update is made.

How could I have just the graph (and not the whole Dashboard) and have it auto-updated?

Answer (score 0):

The Composer is a user interface for helping "compose" your graph. The UI itself is basically a frame containing the generated PNG image. If you right-click on the PNG image you can grab the URL for the image and embed it elsewhere, but you'll still need to manually refresh the image or write some JavaScript to refresh it automatically.

Comment: Are there somewhere some instructions how to do this JavaScript? Or are there other tools (like e. g. Grafana) to do this easily?